# When creating a nerd in my nerd_table I get the following error

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code from create_users_table.php

```
public function up()
    {
      Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('nerd_level');
       });
    }
```

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'nerd_level' in 'field list' (SQL: insert
>   into `users` (`name`, `email`, `nerd_level`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (dasdasd, vincentnelissen@hotmail.nl, 1,
>   2017-03-31 15:41:51, 2017-03-31 15:41:51))

And when I try to edit a nerd I get the following error:

> ErrorException in 17afaeb4afd6b4276e6af6ff12921ab25d74a9cc.php line
>   22: Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   /var/www/vhosts/vincentspage.tk/httpdocs/Laravel/resources/views/nerds/edit.blade.php)

This is my code from edit.blade.php:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
        <title>Look! I'm CRUDding</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap
        /3.0.0  /css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
<body>
<div class="container">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ URL::to('nerds') }}">Nerd Alert</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('nerds') }}">View All Nerds</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('nerds/create') }}">Create a Nerd</a>
  </ul>
 </nav>

 <h1>Edit {{ $nerd->name }}</h1>

 <!-- if there are creation errors, they will show here -->
  {{ HTML::ul($errors->all()) }}

 {{ Form::model($nerd, array('route' => array('nerds.update',  
  $nerd->id),   'method' => 'PUT')) }}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
    {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
    {{ Form::email('email', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('nerd_level', 'Nerd Level') }}
    {{ Form::select('nerd_level', array('0' => 'Select a Level', '1' => 
    'Sees Sunlight', '2' => 'Foosball Fanatic', '3' => 'Basement 
    Dweller'), null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>

{{ Form::submit('Edit the Nerd!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

 {{ Form::close() }}

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And when I try to delete a nerd This is the error:

> FatalErrorException in NerdController.php line 128: Call to a member
>   function delete() on null

return Redirect is php line 128

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    // delete
    $nerd = User::find($id);
    $nerd->delete();

    // redirect
    Session::flash('message', 'Successfully deleted the nerd!');
    return Redirect::to('nerds');
}
```

This Error can be profitable to others who have similar problems , so they know what to change in their code as well. Or not to make a similar mistake to whoever reads it first.

Can anyone help me ?

Kind regards,

Vincent

Comment: Can you show line 128 on NerdController.php? Also, whatever delete is being called on, can you show everything to see how that variable came to be null?

Comment: After you create the table, verify that nerd_level exists as a column.

Comment: without seeing your php code and the basic structure of you sql table it makes it hard to help, also what variant of sql are you using?

Comment: Did you add the column to your migration before or after you migrated? `describe nerd_table` to verify that the column exists.

Comment: isn't it this line ?    $table->integer('nerd_level');

Comment: @Goose it is added

Comment: Does the $id variable actually a user id?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `describe users` or `show create table users` in mysql?

Comment: If this is new code, you should stick to Laravel's conventions for table names. It should be `nerds`, not `nerd_table`. Calling things stuff like `user_table` or `tblUser` fell out of style looooong ago.

Answer (score 3):

instead of `Schema::table` use `Schema::create` for creating new tables. you are using `Schema::table` and application expects that you are trying to modify an existing table.

so it would be something like this for `create_users_table`

```
public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('nerd_level');
       });
    }
```

**Additional information**

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'nerd_level' in 'field list' (SQL: insert
>   into users (name, email, nerd_level, updated_at,  created_at) values
>   (dasdasd, vincentnelissen@hotmail.nl, 1, 2017-03-31 15:41:51,
>   2017-03-31 15:41:51))

This error is because that you are trying to save a record to a table which doesn't have `nerd_level` field on it. so if you have created a migration and ran it first and later when you add the field it wont work. so you need to either rollback migration before bringing any changes to the file or should create a new migration for just adding nerd_level field to the existing table.

1st method

- to rollback the migrations run following command until the create_users_table is rolled back or declare the step. see docs
  [Rolling Back Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#rolling-back-migrations)

  php artisan migrate:rollback
- bring the required changes add following line.

  $table->integer('nerd_level');
- run migration again

  php artisan migrate

2nd method (preferred way). See docs [Modifying Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#modifying-columns)

- leave existing create_users_table as it is without `$table->integer('nerd_level');`
- create a new seperate migration to just add the new column.

> ErrorException in 17afaeb4afd6b4276e6af6ff12921ab25d74a9cc.php line
>   22: Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   /var/www/vhosts/vincentspage.tk/httpdocs/Laravel/resources/views/nerds/edit.blade.php)

this error is because as the error describes you are trying to access a property of null object, it means that you need to first have that user(model) exist on table to be able to access its properties.